# Как установить Windows из Linux?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, windows-10, ос, dual-boot

У меня стоит Ubuntu, но необходимо поставить Windows, флешки более чем на 4 гб нету и дисковода с дисками так же. Как можно сделать это прямо из системы Linux?

Comment: Может не в тему, но попробуйте Винду в виртуалке поднять.

Comment: нууу, желательно ее как основную систему вместо линукса

Comment: Можно подключить реальный жёсткий диск к виртуалке. Правда, нужно предельно чётко понимать, что происходит, чтобы ещё и линукс вдобавок не запороть, так что этот вариант скорее всего не для вас

Comment: Рекомендую не пожалеть пятьсот рублей на покупку флешки на хотя бы 8 гигабайт

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Отбить в физическом начале 100ГБ основного раздела в ntfs.
2. Поставить флаг (в терминологии gparted) `boot`.
3. Распаковать туда образ десятки.
4. Перезагрузиться.
5. Установить 10 с диска C:\ на диск C:.
6. ?????
7. PROFIT!