# Создать загрузочную флешку windows 7

Tags: windows, ubuntu

Нужно создать загрузочную флешку windows 7 на Ubuntu. пробовал через woeusb но она выдаёт 256 ошибку.

Comment: Что делать если нужно установить Windows 7 имея только Ubuntu и флешку.
Думаю, с более поздними версиями тоже будет работать. [https://www.khtulhu.org.ua/programmy/9-ubuntu/255-zapis-zagruzochnoj-fleshki-windows-7-v-ubuntu.html](https://www.khtulhu.org.ua/programmy/9-ubuntu/255-zapis-zagruzochnoj-fleshki-windows-7-v-ubuntu.html)

Comment: Сделал как описанно, не помогло, при загрузки с флешки просто мигает курсор и всё.

Comment: Образ точно загрузочный?

Comment: https://windowsobraz.com/windows-7-64-bit-skachat-torrent/originalnye-obrazy-windows-7/93-chistyy-windows-7-ult-x64-rus-originalnyy-obraz.html отсюда скачал, а как проверить не знаю

Comment: https://remontka.pro/download-windows-10-iso-microsoft/#microsoft
Инструкция как скачать оригинальный образ с сайта M$

Comment: У меня ноутбук 2012 года, и драйвера на сайте производителя есть только на windows 7 и 8, для 10 нет драйверов. Я устанавливал 10 - ку, она устанавливает драйвер wi-fi, который не работает на моём ноуте.

Comment: поэтому мне нужна только 7

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/913900/191416 пункты с 1 по 3. Но для флэшки.

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo apt-add-repository 'deb http://liveusb.info/multisystem/depot all main'

wget -q http://liveusb.info/multisystem/depot/multisystem.asc -O- | sudo apt-key add -

sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install multisystem -y
```

[image]

> Для создания загрузочных USB-носителей из образов CD/DVD в Ubuntu существует немало способов. Одна из самых мощных и универсальных программ для задач такого рода - MultiSystem LiveUSB Multiboot. Она очень проста в обращении, легко устанавливается на компьютер, имеет русифицированный интерфейс. Её главной отличительной особенностью является возможность легко создавать мультизагрузочные USB-носители

Answer (score 0):

Есть несколько утиллит, но лично я предпочитаю использовать `dd` — никогда с ней ещё не было проблем у меня. Подключаете флешку к компьютеру, смотрите список подключенных устройств:

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

Допустим, ваша флешка получила идентификатор `/dev/sdc`. По умолчанию при подключении все накопители монтируются в систему, поэтому том надо отмонтировать:

```
umount /dev/sdc1
```

Далее пишете образ на флешку (обратите внимание, что используется идентификатор самого устройства, а не логического тома):

```
sudo dd if=windows.iso of=/dev/sdc bs=4M
```

После записи образа на флешку:

```
sync
sudo eject /dev/sdc
```

Профит.

Comment: Сделал так, при загрузки с флешки пишет что это не загрузочный диск ....

Comment: @РоманЮсупов тогда встаёт вопрос, который вам задали в комментах: а диск-то загрузочный? За работу репаков я не ручаюсь. А вот официальные образы должны работать.

Comment: Получилось сделать 10, загрузиться с неё, а там уже с помощью Rufus сделал загрузочную семёрку. Теперь у меня две загрузочные флешки для 10 и 7.

Comment: Сейчас хочу поставить 10, но у не не работают дрова для wi fi к моему ноуту lenovo g780. А Драва которые скучал с сайта Lenovo для моей модели - там для windows 7,  и 10 их отказывается устанавливать - пишет что по несовместимо с системой. Как мне удалить установленные дрова на 10 от Wi-Fi и установить родные дрова?

Comment: @РоманЮсупов что касается драйверов, то я вам не подскажу. Я мало пользуюсь виндой. В основном Linux и macOS. А что касается драйверов, то я никогда не сталкивался с проблемами. Что мой новый ПК на райзене, что мой старый ПК 2005 года заводятся на 10-ке и все драйвера работают.

Comment: Кажется я решил проблему, драйвера не устанавливаются с сайта производителя, потому как там только для 7 и 8. Но я установил другой драйвер, который есть в системе , но винда считает его несовместимым, но тем не менее сейчас работает, и wi-fi не отваливается, поиграл несколько каток в танках, там постояно сеть отваливалась, сейчас вроде нормально, сеть держиться.